# Where does static production data live in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm developing on a game currently. It's a capitalism game of sorts, buying, selling, quests and such.

As I develop features, stores and items and things. I know I'm eventually going to want to put all this hardcoded data somewhere. In development, it's currently being fed into the database via `db/seeds.rb`. Is there a better place to put the data that I know will be static in production? Really the only data that is going to be changing dynamically is data having to do with users and join tables between users and the static data.

In past applications I've put a bit of static data in migrations, but this games static data will be significantly more than when I did that. Is there a best practice for this?

Here's some example data in `db/seeds.rb` that I think might have a better home:

```
pencil = Item.create(name: "pencil", value: 2, karma: 0)
lemon = Item.create(name: "lemon", value: 4, karma: 0)
pog = Item.create(name: "pog", value: 2, karma: 0)

child_store_items = [pencil, lemon, pog]
child_store = Store.create(name: "KB Toystore", karma: nil, min_age: 0)
child_store_items.each do |item|
  StoreItem.create(store: child_store, item: item, quantity: 30)
end

school_quest = Quest.create(reward: 50, req_age: 0, req_time: 5, description: "learn all the things", title: "go to school")
school_quest_req = QuestItemRule.create(item: pencil, quantity: 3, quest: school_quest, rule: QuestItemRule.rules[:requirement])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with having a config table in your database, but it's a bit overkill.

You can use a gem like [railsconfig](https://github.com/railsconfig/config) for application configuration. If you're talking about model configuration, where you have different constants or collections for different use cases, then I'd recommend creating a class for that whose methods return the values you need, itself optionally and/or partially setup with the help of a configuration gem. Depending on the nature of your static data, [i18n](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) might be useful here, too.

Comment: hmm I'm a bit confused. Are you saying the data shouldn't live at the database level? It should be some sort of configuration?

Comment: It sounds like it is configuration. Is it not? Hard to tell, maybe an example would help because that's what I mean by "depending on the nature."

Comment: added a bit of stuff currently in my seed file

Comment: another thing to note, it that item value will fluctuate depending on user purchases and sales of that item so, don't know if thats necessarily configurable

Comment: That's exactly what `seeds.db` is for, so I'd keep it the way you have it. If I added anything, it would be to guard your creates with `first_or_create` so that it's idempotent.

Comment: Does the app care whether value changes? If not, I'd say that you're simply seeding with initial values and be done with it. If you have to have different initial conditions for items depending on other factors, then you're going to need something more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could store those things in YAML files...

[Here is a YAML tutorial](http://rhnh.net/2011/01/31/yaml-tutorial)